# How to keep an angular universal running

Tags: angular, vpn, angular-universal, gnu-screen

I have an angular universal app on a VPN. I want to keep universal server running and restarting when it crashes.

I use "screen" on the ssh terminal but somehow after a while the server always shut down  even though the screen is always attached.

Is there a way to keep an angular universal server running and restarting in case it stop?There has to be something other wise there is no use of angular universal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), which will monitor your app and restart it if it crashes

**pm2config.json**

```
{
  "apps": [
       {
    "name": "universalServer",
    "script": "./projectName/server.js", //path to your server.js/main.js file
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "",
    },
    "env_production": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    },
    }
  ]
}
```

You can start your server like this

```
pm2 start pm2config.json --env production
```